# Angular 2 How do I create a nested structure?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a set of expressions, and a ConditionSet when you select that one there will be create a new Expression line this one is nested. I created this as object object:

```
export class Expression {
    selector: string;
    constraint: string;
    value: string;
    children: Expression[];
}
```

So when this ConditionSet is selected I want to "move" or duplicate this to Expression.children. Now if I `console.log` this.expressions by adding one it looks as following:

[image]

But like you see the middle select box is nested and the arrivalDate has to be nested in the conditionSet.children like this:

```
Expression { 
selector: "conditionSet",
value:"" 
children: 
          selector:"ArrivalDate", 
          value:"" 
 }
```

And the nested addButton also have to push it to the `.children` to create the nested content.

I was thinking in this way but this does not work :(:

```
if(this.expression.selector === 'conditionSet'){
            this.prototypes = this.prototypes.children;
            console.log(this.prototypes);
        }
```

Can somebody help me out on this, I am really getting desperate on this issue.

Here is a [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/2soqqn?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't have the `addExpression` method defined into your `ExpressionComponent` class, only in the `ExpressionBuilderComponent` one. So you can only add expression for the first level...

Moreover I think that you don't manage correctly the recursive aspect of your data.

For the `ExpressionBuilderComponent` component, you need to provide the `expresion.children` array for the `expressions` parameter of the `expression` component:

```
<expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions" [prototypes]="prototypes" [expression]="expression" [expressions]="expression.children"></expression>
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()">Add Expression</button>
```

The same must be done for the `ExpressionComponent` itself:

```
<div class="col-xs-3">
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedPrototypeSelector" (ngModelChange)="onPrototypeChange()">
    <option *ngFor="#p of prototypes" [value]="p.selector">
      {{ p.selectorName }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
  <div [ngClass]="{'nested-expression': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}">
    <expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions" [prototypes]="prototypes" [expression]="expression" [expressions]="expression.children"></expression>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()">Add Expression</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/zGcoZD?p=preview.

**Edit**

Regarding deletion, you need to handle a custom event (@Ouput) to do that since you need to remove the element from the children of the parent:

```
<div class="col-xs-1">
  <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" (click)="deleteExpression()">Delete</button>
</div>

<div *ngIf="prototype?.valueType === 'Set'">
  <div [ngClass]="{'nested-expression': prototype?.valueType === 'Set'}">
    <expression *ngFor="#expression of expressions"
            [prototypes]="prototypes"
            [expression]="expression"
            [expressions]="expression.children"
            (expressionDeleted)="onExpressionDeleted(expression)">
    </expression>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addExpression()">Add Expression</button>
  </div>
  <div>{{expression | json}}</div>
</div>
```

and in the component:

```
export class ExpressionComponent implements OnInit {
  (...)
  @Output() expressionDeleted: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter;

  (...)

  deleteExpression() {
    this.expressionDeleted.emit();
  }

  onExpressionDeleted(expression) {
    var index = this.expressions.indexOf(this.expression);
    this.expressions.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(index);
  }
}
```

See this plunkr for deletion: https://plnkr.co/edit/rQCILc?p=preview.

Comment: Maybe you could help me with this as well I also want to delete expressions: https://plnkr.co/edit/2soqqn?p=preview

Comment: I would leverage a custom event (`@Ouput`) to do that since you need to remove the element from the children of the parent ;-) See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/rQCILc?p=preview.